# same color scheme during update, insert and read only modes of details view

Tags: asp.net, insert, detailsview, mode, theming

In asp.net Detailsview has several predefined templates but these template changes according to details view mode. Like if the details view has update mode then it will have different color scheme (though template is same).
Problem: i want to apply same color scheme during update, insert and read only modes of details view plz help some body.

Answer (score 0):

You might have given **EditRowStyle** in **DetailsView** just comment it that and check.